# How to read an int from a byte[] with an offset and a size of bits in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, byte, bit

I need a function that takes as parameters an offset and a size of bits to read an int value from a byte array.

```
int GetInt(byte[] data, int bitOffset, int bitSize)
```

For example, I have the following array of bytes:

```
66 DC 00 00 6A DC 00 00
66 DC 00 00 58 DC 00 00
54 DC 00 00 50 DC 00 00
4C DC 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08
F0 FF FF 9F F4 7F 20 9A
91 EB 85 88 3F 6E 00 80
3D 6E 00 80 3B 6E 00 00
```

Same in bits:

```
01100110  00111011  00000000  00000000  01010110  00111011  00000000  00000000
01100110  00111011  00000000  00000000  00011010  00111011  00000000  00000000
00101010  00111011  00000000  00000000  00001010  00111011  00000000  00000000
00110010  00111011  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00010000
00001111  11111111  11111111  11111001  00101111  11111110  00000100  01011001
10001001  11010111  10100001  00010001  11111100  01110110  00000000  00000001
10111100  01110110  00000000  00000001  11011100  01110110  00000000  00000000
```

How do I most efficiently ensure that the following function has these return values?:

```
var a = GetInt(data, 0, 32); // a = 56422
var b = GetInt(data, 313, 11); // b = 4
```

[image]

EDIT: Here the bytes as an C# Array:

```
new byte[] { 0x66, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6A, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x58, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x9F, 0xF4, 0x7F, 0x20, 0x9A, 0x91, 0xEB, 0x85, 0x88, 0x3F, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3D, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3B, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

EDIT 2:
I have already implemented my own solution as well, with which i could take all the values for this post here. Im just very unhappy with my solution because i dont want to pass the array into a BitArray every time. To read a file, this function is called several hundred thousand times.

```
public static int GetdInt(this byte[] data, int bitOffset, int bitSize)
{
    var bits = new BitArray(data);

    var output = 0;

    for(var bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < bitSize; bitIndex++)
    {
        var bit = bits.Get(bitOffset + bitIndex) ? 1 : 0;
        output |= bit << bitIndex;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: please post your bytes in c# so that someone can easily write a unit test (for example `var data = new bytes[]{101,255,1,3,...}`)

Comment: What is the endian-ness of the bytes?

Comment: Your bits are backwards. 0xDC is 11011100.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: @NigelBess I have edited the question above! The bits have the order they appear when passed into a BitArray object.

Comment: Why the first parameter isn't a BitArray object ? Dealing with byte[] will be so much harder

Comment: The bit order is fine according to the desired outcomes, they're just listed from least significant to most significant in the image

Comment: If performance is the primary concern, an unsafe pointer is likely to be the most performant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code. Probably the most appropriate implementation would be `BitConverter` using a `Span`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-6.0#system-bitconverter-toint32(system-readonlyspan((system-byte))) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-span-1-ctor(-0()-system-int32-system-int32). In both cases, endianness is a consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## C# 90 bytes

```
    int GetInt(byte[] d,int o,int b)=>Enumerable.Range(o,b).Sum(i=>(d[i/8]>>i%8)%2>0?1<<i-o:0);
```

I've written this in code golfed form to poke fun at the fact that your question reads like code golf, and that you haven't shown any attempt of your own ;)

Here is a unit test for any future answerers. (OP this might be helpful to you, too):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var bytes = new byte[]
    {
        0x66, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6A, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x66, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x58, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x54, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x4C, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08,
        0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x9F, 0xF4, 0x7F, 0x20, 0x9A,
        0x91, 0xEB, 0x85, 0x88, 0x3F, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x80,
        0x3D, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3B, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x00
    };
    RunTest(0, 32, 56422);
    RunTest(313, 11, 4);

    void RunTest(int offset, int bitSize, int expected)
    {
        var actual = GetInt(bytes, offset, bitSize);
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Edit: Since you showed your own attempt here is a non code-golfed answer:

```
//first write a function that gets a bit value from the byte[]
bool GetBitFromByteArray(byte[] data, int bitNumber)
{
    //8 bits per byte.
    const int sizeOfByte = 8;
    
    var byteNumber = bitNumber / sizeOfByte;//index within the byte array. Integer division always rounds down
    var bitNumberWithinTheByte = bitNumber % sizeOfByte;//bit index within that byte

    //now write a function that gets a bit value from a byte
    return GetBitFromByte(data[byteNumber], bitNumberWithinTheByte);
}

bool GetBitFromByte(byte byteValue, int bitNumber)
{
    //bit shift so that the bit in question is in the least significant place
    var shifted = byteValue >> bitNumber;

    //mod 2 checks if the least significant bit is 0 or 1
    return shifted % 2 > 0;
}

int GetInt(byte[] data, int offset, int bitCount)
{
    //get bit values in order
    var bitValues = new List<bool>(bitCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; i++)
    {
        bitValues.Add(GetBitFromByteArray(data, i + offset));
    }

    //sum up the bit values as powers of 2
    var intValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; i++)
    {
        var bitValue = bitValues[i];
        if (bitValue) intValue += 1 << i;//1<<i is equivalent to 2^i
    }

    return intValue;
}
```

If you are worried about performance and array allocation, the code golfed answer will actually be better.

Comment: Because you said I didn't show my own attempt, I re-edited my question and added to it. I like the functional way of your solution! Tomorrow I will have a closer look at it.

Comment: Now that Ive had time to read everything carefully, heres my big thanks! Wow! The explanations in the second solution were very helpful. However, the code golf version is used since performance is more important to me here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray) and [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter)

```
int GetInt(byte[] data, int bitOffset, int bitSize)
{
    var bits = new BitArray(data).RightShift(bitOffset);
    bits.Length = bitSize;
    var bytes = new byte[4];
    bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possible strategy, reading the bytes one-by-one until enough bits have been read, and then discarding any excess. Passed the two test cases, but that's not sufficient testing IMO, do some more.

```
static int GetInt(byte[] data, int bitOffset, int bitSize)
{
    // first chunk is special, lower bits are discarded immediately
    // to prevent trying to put more than 32 bits in `result`
    // when `bitSize == 32` and `bitOffset != 0`
    int byteOffset = bitOffset >> 3;
    int result = data[byteOffset] >> (bitOffset & 7);
    int resultOffset = 8 - (bitOffset & 7);
    // the "rest", whole bytes are read from data and put into their place in the result
    while (resultOffset < bitSize)
    {
        byteOffset++;
        result |= data[byteOffset] << resultOffset;
        resultOffset += 8;
    }
    // in general too many bits have been read at this point, discard excess
    return result & (int)(uint.MaxValue >> -bitSize);
}
```

There are other possible strategies. For example, reading a whole `int` or `long` with the `BitConverter` class (or other tricks) and then doing some shifting and masking to extract the target range of bits from that. That has the potential to be more efficient, but has some unfortunate details to take care of when the target range doesn't cross the end of the array but the byte-aligned integer that contains them would.

The way the excess bits are discarded at the end doesn't work properly when `bitSize = 0`, which I did not think is interesting to support, but could be done easily by handling that as a special case. Unlike `(1 << bitSize) - 1`, the way I used does work for 32 bits.